# Hosting WCF app in IIS 6 - localhost replaced with machine name

Tags: wcf, silverlight-3.0, iis-6

I've recently moved my Silverlight solution off of Casini (one for service, one for SL app) and over to IIS to simulate production. It's one website on a port (localhost:2002) containing two web applications, one for my SL app and one for my WCF service. Everything works fine in Casini with a clientaccesspolicy xml file, but in IIS something is replacing localhost:2002 with my machine name in the WSDL. What causes that, and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS, the domain of the website vis replaced by the machinename unless there are host headers configured. This is also true with SSL, though you have to use adsutil to change an SSL host header.